# Create temporary postgres database for (unit) testing purposes

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, testing

For testing purposes, unit-test or integration-test, I need a temporary postgres database that I will simply throw away after I am done. I do not want to use a potentially existing postgres database on the system. Nor should it be assumed that there is such a database already running. I do not want to cross any isolation boundaries. The only given is that the postgres binaries are installed.

How can I create a temporary postgres database for testing purposes, that I can easily throw away once I am finished?

Comment: There is no `CREATE TEMP DATABASE` equivalent to  `CREATE TEMP TABLE`. You will just need to `CREATE DATABASE` and then `DROP DATABASE`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following bash script. Note that `T` below should point to a directory under which we will create the files for the postgres database.

```bash
die() {
    >&2 echo "ERROR: $@"
    exit 1
}

POSTGRES_DIR="${T}"/postgres
initdb "${POSTGRES_DIR}" || die "Failed to initialize postgres directory"

PORT=11123
postgres -D "${POSTGRES_DIR}" \
         -k "${POSTGRES_DIR}" \
         -p "${PORT}" &
POSTGRES_PID=${!}

TIMEOUT_SECS=30
timeout "${timeout_secs}" bash -c \
        'until printf "" >/dev/tcp/${0}/${1} 2>> "${T}/portlog"; do sleep 1; done' \
        localhost "${PORT}" || die "Timeout waiting for postgres port ${PORT} to become available"

psql -h "${POSTGRES_DIR}" -p "${PORT}" -d postgres <<-EOF || die "Failed to configure postgres"
create database mydatabase;
create user myuser with encrypted password 'changeme';
grant all privileges on database mydatabase to myuser;
\connect mydatabase
grant all on schema public to myuser;
EOF

(
    cleanup() {
        kill "${POSTGERS_PID}" || die "failed to send SIGTERM to postgres"
    }
    trap cleanup exit

    <use postgres here>
)
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new cluster via `initdb` in order to create a database?

Comment: Fair point, I tried to make the motivation clearer in the question.